# Adding additional data to WP_Post object

Tags: posts, wp-query, api

I want to add additional items to the data returned as [`WP_Post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post). So for every function/query that returns a WP_Post object I want my additional data added.

Example of returned result:

```
WP_Post (object) => [
    // Default data returned by WP_Post
    ID                  => int,
    post_author         => string,
    post_name           => string,
    post_type           => string,
    post_title          => string,
    post_date           => string,
    post_date_gmt       => string,
    post_content        => string,
    post_excerpt        => string,
    post_status         => string,
    comment_status      => string,
    ping_status         => string,
    post_password       => string,
    post_parent         => int,
    post_modified       => string,
    post_modified_gmt   => string,
    comment_count       => string,
    menu_order          => string,

    // Additional data I want to add
    extra_data_1        => array,
    more_data_key       => string,
    another_added       => string
]
```

For example when the functions [`get_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/) or [`get_page_by_path()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_path/) are run they will return the WP_Post object along with my additional data.

I've tried finding the appropriate [hook/filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) but this has been unsuccessful.

I am hoping I can do something like:

```
// This is concept code
add_action('pre_wp_post_return', function($data) {
    $data->extra_data_1     = get_post_meta($data->ID, 'extra_data');
    $data->more_data_key    = get_post_meta($data->ID, 'more_data', true);
    $data->another_added    = get_post_meta($data->ID, 'another_data', true);

    return $data;
});
```

My reasoning is I am having to build a custom API for WP that uses a range of different core functions which return WP_Post objects. Being able to add my additional data in one place would prevent me from duplicating code.

I hope this is clear enough. Any help would be great!

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't wat to use [`post_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta)?

Comment: @cjbj I have post meta applied to the posts but the `WP_Post` object does not include this by default. I have updated my question to stop confusion. My reasoning is I am having to build a custom API for WP that uses a range of different core functions which return `WP_Post` objects. Being able to add my additional data in one place would prevent me from duplicating code.

Comment: Understood your point. I'll delete my answer. I've just looked through post.php and class-wp-post and didn't find a single action hook or filter hook. That's bad news for the idea you're trying to create here.

Comment: To prevent duplicating code, why not write your own wrapper functions that return values from both the post object and its metadata?  That seems a simpler approach.

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook This is currently how I am doing it but was wondering if there was a better solution.

Comment: Depends on how you define "better" :-)  To my mind a solution that gives you the functions that you need without messing with the internals of WP seems pretty good.  There are already functions to get a post field and get a post meta field, so wrapping those with half a dozen lines of code is quick and easy, doesn't break anything else and will also use any caching that the built-in functions already implement.

Comment: One could use [`the_post` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_post/) to add in additional properties in theory. Should you do this though is definitely debatable.

Answer (score 11):

If your extra data directly references a post meta you don't have to do anything, because `WP_Post` implements the »magic« methods [`__isset()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/0b81d79c868a3ed3eedbee53805f1cdad5d90351/wp-includes/class-wp-post.php#L252) and [`__get()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/0b81d79c868a3ed3eedbee53805f1cdad5d90351/wp-includes/class-wp-post.php#L274) which directly asks for post meta keys (except for the following four keys: `page_template`, `post_category`, `tags_input` and `ancestors`). Here's a quick example that shows the behavior:

```
<?php
$post_id = 42;
$meta_key = 'extra_data_1';
add_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, [ 'some', 'value' ], TRUE );
$post = get_post( $post_id );
var_dump( $post->{$meta_key} ); // (array) ['some', 'value']
```

In any other case, use the filter [`posts_results`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/0b81d79c868a3ed3eedbee53805f1cdad5d90351/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L2866):

```
<?php
add_filter(
    'posts_results',
    function( array $posts, WP_Query $query ) {
        foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
            $post->extra_data_1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'extra_data' );
            // and so on …
        }

        return $posts;
    },
    10,
    2
);
```

However I would suggest to use an object oriented approach and create own entity interfaces, that follows your problem domain. The implementations then wrapping `WP_Post` instances as a dependency. For example, let's say you're dealing with *books*:

```
<?php

namespace Wpse240042\Type;

use WP_Post;

interface Book {

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function title();

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function publisher();

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function year();
}

class WpPostBook implements Book {

    /**
     * @var WP_Post
     */
    private $post;

    /**
     * @param WP_Post $post
     */
    public function __construct( WP_Post $post ) {

        $this->post = $post;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function title() {

        return $this->post->post_title;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function publisher() {

        return get_post_meta( $this->post->ID, '_book_publisher', TRUE );
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function year() {

        return get_post_meta( $this->post->ID, '_book_publisher', TRUE );
    }
}
```

Your business logic can then rely on the structure of a *book* by type hint the type `Book` on every dependency. To fetch a list of books you could implement a factory in the first step that wraps a `WP_Query` or fetch WP_Query arguments and return a list of book instances. You should not use the `posts_results` filter in that case to replace `WP_Query::posts` with a list of `Type\Book` instances to not break type consistency throughout WP core.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; You can't and you shouldn't.

It is [impossible to extend the `WP_post` class](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/class-wp-post.php#L22) with extra fields, because it has been defined as ['final'](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php). You perhaps could get around that by wrapping the class in another class ([tutorial](https://github.com/mhull/helping-friendly-plugin/blob/master/lib/class-hphp-post.php)), but it still is not advisable.

All kinds of themes and plugins rely on the [metadata being stored as metadata](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta). You may get it to work right now, but you'll probably regret it in the future, when you find out that some plugin you want to use cannot handle the way you have stored your metadata.

Comment: He just want to add public properties to an arbitrary object. This is possible irrespective of the extensibility of the class declaration. Also there's the `posts_result` filter.

Comment: @David I checked that in the comments to the question, OP explicitly wants to extend the `wp_post` class, not use `add_post_meta`.

Comment: For what I see he/she wants to extend post _objects_ not the class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but thought share a working solution
This can be achieved by doing:

```
$posts = get_posts( 
    array(
        "post_type" => $post_type->name,
        "numberposts" => -1 
    )
);
foreach($posts as &$post)
{
    $custom_fields = (array)$post;
    // add extra field(s) like this
    $custom_fields["posttype_link"] = get_permalink($post->ID);
    $post = (object)$custom_fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **the_post** hook: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_post/

You will be modifying the global **$post** object so no need to return it as if it was a filter. The 2 params **$post** and **$query** are passed for reference.