# Metadata on the WP_Post object

Tags: php, custom-field, post-meta

I'm having trouble understanding the behavior of a `WP_Post` variable (and / or possibly the behavior of `var_dump` itself).

As far as I know, `var_dump` will inspect all data from a variable. From the PHP documentation:

> This function displays structured information about one or more expressions that includes its type and value. Arrays and objects are explored recursively with values indented to show structure.

**Then, why is it that `var_dump($post)` doesn't show metadata, whereas `var_dump($post->metadata)` does?**

I've already read the offficial documentation, specially [this particular comment](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/#comment-1894), as well as [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/240051/22510). I assume the explanation is there, in plain sight -- however, it's still unclear to me.

What's going on here? Is it some basic PHP behavior that I'm not aware? (I'm not sure if this question is because a lack of understanding how WordPress works or how PHP works. Sorry if this is the wrong site to ask).

Comment: The answer you linked to explains how it works, with a link to the source code that does it.

Comment: I don't understand it.

Comment: [What are PHP Magic Methods?](https://www.culttt.com/2014/04/16/php-magic-methods/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'magic' in it, but there are two `magic` methods of `WP_Post` class, `__isset()`, and `__get()`.

Your `extra_data` is not a property of `WP_Post` class, so first `var_dump` does not include it.

A reference to non existing property of `WP_Post` employs those `magic` methods, mentioned above, to retrieve post's metadata.

First, `$post->__isset('extra_data')` will be executed, if `false` is returned, then `$post->extra_data` will be an empty array, otherwise `$post->__get('extra_data')` will run, returning metadata. That's why your second `var_dump` shows `extra_data`.

**Note:** Milo's first comment to this question is, in fact, the perfect answer.

Comment: The core of my question is why doesn't `var_dump` include it? Isn't the very purpose of var_dump to dump *everything* from a variable?

Comment: The second paragraph of my answer explains it. `extra_data` is not a property of `WP_Post`, and direct reference to it does not make it as such. It simply attempts to retrieve metadata with a key equals to 'extra_data'.