# What is proper filter or hook action to add data to the $post object?

Tags: posts, post-meta

I have a custom post type that has a one to many relationship with another custom post type. Call them `lesson` and `topics`. Currently, I get `$topics` as

```
$args = array(
                'meta_key' => 'lesson_id',
                'meta_value' => $post['post']->ID,
                'post_type' => 'plugin-topic',
                'post_status' => 'published',
                'posts_per_page' => -1
            );
            $les_topics = get_posts($args);
```

However, when the `$lesson` object is created by wordpress for first time, I would like to add $topics to it so that I can reference as $lesson->topics.

Can someone tell me the appropriate filter or action to use to accomplish that? I saw this

[Adding additional data to WP_Post object](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/240042/adding-additional-data-to-wp-post-object)

which suggests I shouldn't even do what I am asking to do but it isn't clear why this would be a bad thing.

thanks!
Brian

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/ (looking at the source code) you could use `wp_insert_post_data` [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_post_data/) and inject your relation, whenever a post is inserted.

`$post` is usually a global variable though when a page is loaded, which you can adjust using `the_post` [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_post/)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense about the global $post object.  The thing with wp_insert_post_data is that I just want to have this additional data upon the post retrieval before I display it, not upon post insertion tot he db. спасибо!